# how to get a white light on a uibutton click

Tags: iphone

i just saw a code sample of uiwebview on icodeblog. It has a Address bar button. When i tap over that it displays a white light in the background of button. The image is flashy and looked good to me. Can some one tell me how to do that??
  thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [showTouchWhenHighlighted](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) property of your UIButton to YES.